# mentioning user from database on triggering @ event in suneditor

Tags: reactjs, mention, suneditor

I am using Suneditor in reactjs. Now here i want to mention some user name from database while writing description.But i am not able to find any "mention" plugin using suneditor.Is there any way i can implement it using suneditor? Mentioned username will be marked as blue and underlined.Any reference link would be appereciated using suneditor.

```
<MentionsInput
    className="comments-textarea"
    placeholder=""
    value={this.state.value}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    onSelect={this.handleSelection}
    onBlur={this.handleBlur}
    markup={this.state.markup}
    autoFocus
>
    <Mention
        className="comment-user"
        type="user"
        trigger="@"
        data={this.state.totalUserList}
    />
</MentionsInput>
```

I have used react mention plugin previously.Can i use it in suneditor with fullfilling above requirement?